Need help Implementing Context aware decoding on Llama
I have written the code below, but I run into the following error:
AttributeError: 'CAD' object has no attribute 'generate'

I want to override the forward function without rewriting the generate function how am I supposed to do this?
class CAD(AutoModelForCausalLM):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("huggyllama/llama-13b")
        self.tokenizer.pad_token = self.tokenizer.eos_token
        self.alpha = 0.5
  
    @classmethod
    def from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs):
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("huggyllama/llama-13b", **kwargs)
        model.__class__ = cls  # Change the class to CAD
        model.alpha = 0.5  # Add the custom alpha attribute
        model.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("huggyllama/llama-13b")
        model.tokenizer.pad_token = model.tokenizer.eos_token
        return model


    def forward(self, input_ids,attention_mask,*args, **kwargs):
        #to be overwritten
        return final_logits


model_name = "huggyllama/llama-13b"
cad_model = 
CAD.from_pretrained(model_name,torch_dtype=torch.float16,low_cpu_mem_usage=True,use_cache=True)

inputs = ['Better late than']
contexts = ['Write a quote that ends in the word "early":']
contexts = None

text_token = cad_model.tokenizer(inputs ,return_tensors='pt')
input_ids = text_token['input_ids']
inputs_and_contexts = input_ids

if contexts:
    inputs_with_contexts = [context + cad_model.tokenizer.eos_token + input_text for context, input_text in zip(contexts, inputs)]
    text_token_with_contexts = cad_model.tokenizer(inputs_with_contexts, return_tensors="pt", padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=256)
    inputs_and_contexts = text_token_with_contexts['input_ids']
    attention_mask = text_token_with_contexts['attention_mask']

output = cad_model.generate([22,33],
                            attention_mask=attention_mask,
                            # eos_token_id=cad_model.tokenizer.eos_token_id,
                            max_new_tokens=1,
                            # pad_token_id=cad_model.tokenizer.pad_token_id
                        )
generated_text = cad_model.tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
generated_text 


I have also tried
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name,torch_dtype=torch.float16,low_cpu_mem_usage=True,use_cache=True)
model.__class__ = CAD  # Change the model class to use the custom forward


but I encounter the same error.
